# Load Data into Hbase outside Client Node

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Thanks in advance.
We are loading data into Hbase using Java. It's pretty straight and works fine when we run the program on the client node (edge node). But we want to run this program remotely (outside the hadoop cluster) within our network to load the data.
Is there anything required to do this in terms of security on the hadoop cluster? When I run the program outside the cluster it's hanging..

Please advise. Greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks

### Code here

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Delete;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

import com.dev.stp.cvsLoadEventConfig;
import com.google.protobuf.ServiceException;

public class LoadData {


static String ZKHost;
static String ZKPort;
private static Configuration config = null;

private static String tableName;


public LoadData (){

    //Set Application Config
    LoadDataConfig conn = new LoadDataConfig();
    ZKHost = conn.getZKHost();
    ZKPort = conn.getZKPort();

    config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", ZKHost);
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", ZKPort);
    config.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");

    tableName = "E_DATA";
}   


//Insert Record
    try {
        HTable table = new HTable(config, tableName);

        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(eventId));
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("E_DETAILS"), Bytes.toBytes("E_NAME"),Bytes.toBytes("test data 1"));   
        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("E_DETAILS"), Bytes.toBytes("E_TIMESTAMP"),Bytes.toBytes("test data 2"));


        table.put(put);
        table.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Print the code you use to run program remotely

Comment: Hi..added the code..Thanks much for your help

Comment: Did you try to remove `zookeeper.znode.parent` option or change it to `/hbase` value?

Comment: Tried that..no luck...it's just hanging